# Software to convert MP3 to MIDI and MP3 to KAROKE 

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, conversion, midi

I am looking for software that can convert MP3 files to MIDI and KAROKE formats.

Answer (score 3):

To convert from Mp3 to Midi you can use [AmazingMidi](http://www.audiorecording.me/convert-mp3-files-to-midi-files-using-amazingmidi-in-linux-ubuntu-wine.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20audiorecording%20%28Audio%20Recording%3a%20Mixing%20Tips%20&%20Techniques%20%7C%20Building%20Home%20Recording%20Computer%29) on [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

Or by [using Audacity](http://www.ehow.com/how_5065985_convert-mp-audacity.html).

To Convert MP3 to Karaoke Audio, you can [use MP3 Karaoke 6.0.1](http://gamblis.com/2011/06/24/convert-mp3-to-karaoke-audio-using-mp3-karaoke-6-0-1/).

Comment: Please note that both of these conversions are not very reliable as no perfect software exists yet. Even the best implementation are very crude and make many mistakes.